# Fundamental period of periodic delta function

Tags: signal, delta

I have the following signal:

$$ x[n] = X\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}
(\delta[n − 4k] + \delta[n − 4k − 1] − \delta[n − 4k − 2] − \delta[n − 4k − 3])$$

The fundamental period of this signal is \$4\$. Is this purely because of the factor in front of \$k\$? Secondly, if I were to sketch the signal for 1 period, would the value for \$x[0] = \delta[0] + \delta[-1] - \delta[-2] - \delta[-3]\$? Or would I have to take into consideration the value of k?

Comment: I mean, draw *one* element of the sum – for example, the one you get when setting \$k=0\$. Then change \$k\$ by one. You get periodicity without overlap, so yes, of course, the factor of 4 makes the period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay let's go with the definition of periodicity:

\begin{equation*}
x[n]=x[n+T]
\end{equation*}

which in turn yields:

\begin{eqnarray*}
x[n+T] = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (\delta[n+T-4k]+\delta[n+T-4k-1]-\delta[n+T-4k-2]-\delta[n+T-4k-3]) \\ = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (\delta[n-(4k-T)]+\delta[n-(4k+1-T]-\delta[n-(4k+2-T)]-\delta[n-(4k+3-T)])
\end{eqnarray*}

On inspection, if we allow T=4,

\begin{eqnarray*}
x[n+4] = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (\delta[n-(4k-4)]+\delta[n-(4k+1-4]-\delta[n-(4k+2-4)]-\delta[n-(4k+3-4)]) \\ = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (\delta[n-4(k-1)]+\delta[n-(4k-3)]-\delta[n-(4k-2)]-\delta[n-(4k-1)])
\end{eqnarray*}

Now let *k-1=m* or *m=k+1*. Note that limits on *m* remain the same:

\begin{eqnarray*}
x[n+4] = \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} (\delta[n-4m]+\delta[n-4m-1)]-\delta[n-4m-2]-\delta[n-4m-3)]) \\ = x[n]
\end{eqnarray*}

This explains why the period of x[n] is 4. Naturally, the period is directly related to the coefficient of k, as can be seen in the above equations.

As for x[0], *n* takes the value of 0, but *k* continues to range from -infinity to infinity.

\begin{equation*}
x[0] = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (\delta[-4k]+\delta[-4k-1]-\delta[-4k-2]-\delta[-4k-3])
\end{equation*}